# appending non slice to map of slices

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go, slice

My current code is this:

```
name := "John"
id := "1234"
c := make(map[string][]string)

c["d"] = make([]string, len(d))
c["l"] = make([]string, len(l))

copy(c["d"], d)
copy(c["l"], l)
c["test"] = name
c["id"] = id
```

Assuming d & l are both []string. Go does not let me do this. Is there a way where I would be able to achieve a JSON like this:

{
    "name": "John",
    "id": "1234",
    "d": [
        123,
        456
    ],
    "l": [
        123,
        456
    ]
}

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use `map[string]interface{}` instead.
2. Also you don't need to copy your slices.

Example with `map[string]interface{}`:

```
name := "John"
id := "1234"
l, d := []string{"123", "456"}, []string{"789", "987"}
c := map[string]interface{}{
    "d":    d,
    "l":    l,
    "test": name,
    "id":   id,
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/Ke1lWpb6y3)

Comment: Just to add a little bit to this answer if you know what the data structure is going to be beforehand it is even better/more idiomatic to use a `struct` combined with [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to deal with json in Go